# Read from text file in Turbo C++ 3.0

Tags: c++, turbo-c++, borland-c++

First post. Please let me know if I missed anything, or if you require any more information.

Okay, so what I'm trying to do here is read data from a text file in Turbo C++ 3.0, and then output this text.

Here is my code (updated):

```
ifstream playerData("players.txt");
const int size = 100;
char* dataArray = new char[size];

while(!playerData.eof()){
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        playerData>>dataArray[i];
        if(dataArray[i]=='\n'){
            cout<<"\n";
        }
        cout<<dataArray[i];
    }
}
```

If I have the following text in the players.txt file:

```
ABC - 7 minutes
DEF - 4 minutes
```

Then this is what is outputted:

```
ABC-7minutesDEF-4minutes
```

Comment: Which version of Turbo C++?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Version 3.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what `&(dataArray[i])=="\n"` is supposed to be. It looks like you just guessed things until compiler errors went away. That's not a good way to code any language, let alone C++.

What you've written tests whether the element `dataArray[i]` lives at the same memory address as the literal array `"\n"`.  They certainly don't, so this test will always fail.

If you meant to compare against a char, write `if (dataArray[i] == '\n')`. However, that would still be a mistake because `dataArray[i]` has not been assigned a value yet.  You should move the line to *after* you read into `dataArray[i]`.

Other problems:

- You overflow the buffer, change `i<=size` to `i < size`
- You use `new` for no reason; use an array instead
- You don't check whether your `>>` operation succeeded.
- `while(!playerData.eof())` is a blunder; instead you should break when `>>` fails

Also, Turbo C++ 3.0 came out before the first C++ standard, so it is not a good idea to use it for C++.  In summary:

- learn from a book, not trial-and-error
- Get a modern compiler (there are good free ones)

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll keep that in mind. I updated the code yet it is still not working. Could it be because playerData>>dataArray[i]; doesn't read in line breaks?

Comment: Yes, `>>` does *formatted input* and skips whitespace in this case. If you want unformatted data use `playerData.get(dataArray[i])`.  In Standard C++ you can get a whole line at once although I'm not sure if Turbo C++ 3.0 has that feature.

Comment: Great! Thank you, that works. I think you're right in saying that I should use a newer compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the address of `i`*th* character with the address of const literal `"\n"` which is useless. To compare a character with character `\n`, you should use single quotes: `'\n'` and remove `&` operator also.

```
if (dataArray[i]=='\n')
```

*<sub>Forget Turbo C++ and use new and modern compilers</sub>*

---

**After update**

You should try to use STL and managed containers rather and your pointer stuff and `new/delete`. Moreover, testing by `.eof()` is not a good practice, use the object itself. And to get a line, you can use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) function. Rewriting your code in a standard new compiler:

```
ifstream playerData("players.txt");

while(playerData) {

   string dataArray;

   getline(playerData, dataArray);

   cout << dataArray << '\n';
}
```